# Seeking GIS Library for C# Applications using WPF

Tags: c#, software-recommendations, wpf, sdk, library

This question has been asked multiple times before, but not in the last 5+ years so I think it's worth asking again as I'm struggling and the answer way well be different now.

I want to create a C# application (WPF) which has some GIS capabilities. I'm new to C#, application development and GIS so this should be an interesting challenge. My main objectives are:

- Load (ideally free to use) OpenStreetMap tiles
- Load Shape Files
- Load DXF Files (not critical as could convert to SHP first)
- Add points, lines and polygons
- Interrogate SHP files
- Allow a flat world projection for working in local coordinate systems.

For now the package will be used internally at work, but I wouldn't want to write off the possibility of selling it if it exceeds my expectations so I don't want to base it on free to develop but prohibitively expensive libraries if used commercially.

I have tried the following:

- MapSui for WPF - Very easy to get a basic map started, but I find the documentation just stops after that (at least in a language I can understand) and you have to rely on their examples which for me are too involved for me to pick apart and re-create.
- DotSpatial - I believe to be WinFrom only. Still I could use this.  Again, getting a basic map working was fairly simple (bit more involved than MapSui) but I couldn't work out how to only display the tools I wanted for example. Again, documentation seemed to stop after a basic set up.
- ArcGIS Runtime WPF - Documentation appears to be excellent but it's not free. I find their [Pricing](https://developers.arcgis.com/pricing/) a little confusing. It appears that if you don't use their locator services then it may be free? They mention a monthly developers charge, but unclear if this is for additional services that I don't need? The terms also say you have to allow location services and you can't use it for the "Runtime in a service" which makes no sense to me. If anyone can clarify the above that would be useful. If it can be used for free with local data that would be great.
- SharpMap - Hasn't been updated since 2014 so I may avoid.
- GMap - I don't believe it can operate in flat world or load SHP files which could make it's use very complicated.
- ThinkGeo Desktop Maps - $1000 per year which isn't inline with my expectations from this package.

I seek any suggestions or thought on the best route forward for me?

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't realised that site exists. Should I remove from here and re-post, or is it still valid to ask here? Thanks

Comment: You said "This question has been asked multiple times before".  What are links to those questions?  Personally, I think that you should delete your question from here and post it at [softwarerecs.se] instead.  However, software recommendations are neither explicitly off-topic or explicitly on-topic here and whether community members think they are useful tends to get expressed using their votes.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/78327/10546